# How do I make a class display block with checkbox

Tags: html, css, web, css-selectors, checked

I can get it to work. It works with toggle:checked {display: none} but not with extra class.

```html
 <nav>
        <div class="nav">
          <label class="hamburger__menu" for="toggle">&#9776</label>
          <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="toggle">
        </div>

        <div class="menu-box">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">home</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item menu__item--yellow"><a class="item__link" href="#">humo@festivals</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">humor</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item menu__item--red"><a class="item__link" href="#">video</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">fotospecials</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">nu in humo</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">tv/film</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">actua</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">muziek</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">boeken</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">humo sapiens</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

```
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;

  &:checked + .menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I wont my nav items to come wen I click the icon

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: no I wont It with css it is normaly posibal

Comment: it's just easier with javascript

Answer (score 0):

here's a link to how someone did this with just css https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP

but javascript is much easier

```js
function toggle(){
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0];
if(menu.style.display==='')menu.style.display='block';
else if(menu.style.display==='block')menu.style.display='';
}
```

```css
.menu {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <div class="nav">
          <label class="hamburger__menu" onclick='toggle()'>&#9776</label>
          
        </div>

        <div class="menu-box">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">home</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item menu__item--yellow"><a class="item__link" href="#">humo@festivals</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">humor</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item menu__item--red"><a class="item__link" href="#">video</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">fotospecials</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">nu in humo</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">tv/film</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">actua</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">muziek</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">boeken</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a class="item__link" href="#">humo sapiens</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```